# Getting data using Taleo SOAP API in C# using WSDL

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, taleo

I am using Taleo SOAP API and trying to access some UDF fields for 'Candidate' entity in .NET (c#) I have been able to get the basic fields and related entities fields using the data dictionary (https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/farel9/talentcs_gs/OTPDD/OTPDD.pdf) but I am having trouble getting to UDF fields. Can anyone guide me in the right direction ?

Thank You !!

Comment: Extra Info: I am using WSDL 'FindService'  -> FindPartialEntities call to get the Candidate data

Comment: UPDATE: This is resolved. I used the service call  FindEntities on Candidate Entity  and it listed the UDFs list for the candidate. (Used SoapUI as a test tool)

Comment: Where did you get the WSDL from?